# insert multiple values using a query as array

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to insert multiple data using a query, i've tried the implode function, the while loop, for loop, but still can't be done.. 
can u help plz

well i've a combobox box for selecting course name, created a function to get its ID and assign a variable. supose i'm a manager of a department and need to assign all staff below me a course, i select the course, input the date assigned and expected ending date. i've created another field in database to enter the training owner. Since i'm the 1 assigning the course, my name will appear as owner field.

```
$m_name = $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];
//combobox to get the department ID using variable $dept
//query to get all user concerning the department
$query  = mysql_query("select userid from dept_user where dept_id=$dept LIMIT 0, 30 ");
$row= mysql_query($query);

//from here i'm not being able to execute
 $qry = mysql_query("INSERT INTO course_detail(userid, course_id, date_assign, expected_end_date, owner) VALUES('$query','$name','$sdate', '$edate', '$m_name')" ) ;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not answerable in its current form because you are not giving enough information. Please tell us what format the "multiple data" is in. Show an example.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `$row= mysql_query($query);`? You probably want one of the `mysql_fetch_*` functions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$qry = mysql_query("INSERT INTO course_detail(userid, course_id, date_assign, expected_end_date, owner) VALUES('$query','$name','$sdate', '$edate', '$m_name')" ) ;
```

So, you're basically trying to insert $query in the userid column. In your code, $query is the result of a mysql select statement, thus a multi-array of user ids. Think of it like a simple SQL query, you can't execute that. Even more, you're doing `mysql_query` on a mysql_query result, which is plain wrong. Where does the $dept variable come from? What about the others? If you're sure they're valid here's what you need:

```
// Get the user ids you need to insert in the db
$query = "select userid from dept_user where dept_id=$dept LIMIT 0, 30 "; // this will select the first 30 users in a dept
$buffer = mysql_query($query); // this is a variable that will hold all the results returned by the query above

// While we still have results in the $buffer array, fetch those in the $data array
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($buffer)) {
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO course_detail(userid, course_id, date_assign, expected_end_date, owner) VALUES('".$data['userid']."','$name','$sdate', '$edate', '$m_name')"; // add the userid from the first query and the other data (don't know where you got those
    $insert_buffer = mysql_query($insert_query); // execute the statement above, watch out so you don't overwrite the initial $buffer variable
}
// At this point you should have all the data in database
```

Also, I'm not sure you got the insert statement right

- userid > $data['userid'] (ok)
- course_id > $name (?!)
- date_assign > $sdate (you sure?)
- expected_end_date > $edate (ok)
- owner > $m_name (ok?)

Make sure you have a good naming convention or else you get lost very easy.

Good luck, a lot of mistakes on just 5 lines of code.

Comment: thx dr... its working.. gr8.. txk a lot alot for helping me dr

Comment: Any time, and as the other suggested, read the manual, looks like production stuff to me (users, departments...)

Answer (score 1):

Let's give it a wild guess and assume that this is what you want:

```
//query to get all user concerning the department
$query  = mysql_query("
    SELECT userid 
    FROM dept_user 
    WHERE dept_id=$dept 
");
if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
    $insertSQL = "
        INSERT INTO course_detail 
        (userid, course_id, date_assign, expected_end_date, owner) 
        VALUES
    ";
    $rowsSQL = Array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)){
        $rowsSQL[] = "('{$row['userid']}','$name','$sdate', '$edate', '$m_name')";
    }
    mysql_query($insertSQL.implode(',', $rowsSQL));
}
```

Also you should start reading [the manual](http://php.net).

Answer (score 0):

Read [the doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/insert.html), you can separate each set of data with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = array();    
$values[] = array(
  'id'  => 1,
   'v1' => 'a',
   'v2' => 'b'
);
$values[] = array(
  'id'  => 2,
   'v1' => 'c',
   'v2' => 'd'
);

$sql = "INSERT INTO course_details (id,v1,v2) VALUES ";
foreach ($values as $value) {
  $sql .= '('.$value['id'].','.$value['v1'].','.$value['v2'].'),';
}
$sql = substr ($sql,0,-1) // that will remove the last comma
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the function and here is how to use it

> **Update Query**

```
    $data_array=array(
        "bannername" => addslashes($_POST["bannername"]),
        "url" => $_POST["url"],
        "openin" => $_POST["openin"]
    );

    $param=" bannerid = '$bannerid'";
    $sql=db_makequery("banner",$data_array,"update",$param);
```

> **Insert Query**

```
    $data_array=array(
        "bannername" => addslashes($_POST["bannername"]),
        "url" => $_POST["url"],
        "openin" => $_POST["openin"]
    );

$sql=db_makequery("banner",$data_array);
```

> **Function**

```
function db_makequery($table, $data, $action = 'insert', $parameters = '') 
    {
        reset($data);

        if ($action == 'insert') 
        {
          $query = 'insert into ' . $table . ' (';
          while (list($columns, ) = each($data)) {
            $query .= $columns . ', ';

          }

          $query = substr($query, 0, -2) . ') values (';

          reset($data);
          while (list(, $value) = each($data)) 
          {
            switch ((string)$value) 
            {
              case 'now()':
                $query .= 'now(), ';
                break;
              case 'null':
                $query .= 'null, ';
                break;
              default:
                //$query .= '\'' . tep_db_input($value) . '\', ';
                $query .= '\'' . $value . '\', ';

                break;
            }
          }
          $query = substr($query, 0, -2) . ')';
        }
        elseif ($action == 'update') 
        {
          $query = 'update ' . $table . ' set ';
          while (list($columns, $value) = each($data)) 
          {
            switch ((string)$value) {
              case 'now()':
                $query .= $columns . ' = now(), ';
                break;
              case 'null':
                $query .= $columns .= ' = null, ';
                break;
              default:
                //$query .= $columns . ' = \'' . tep_db_input($value) . '\', ';
                $query .= $columns . ' = \'' . $value . '\', ';
                break;
            }
          }
          $query = substr($query, 0, -2) . ' where ' . $parameters;
        }
        return $query; 
      }
```